# react-native-navigation:compileReactNative57DebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: react-native

I does added in my project react-nativ-navigation library,[Instruction](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing)

I tried to change the variables, because instruction outdated, but I get ERROR after compilations.

Building - completed;
Execution - ERORR

```
Skipping task ':react-native-navigation:javaPreCompileReactNative57Debug' as it is up-to-date.
:react-native-navigation:javaPreCompileReactNative57Debug (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.005 secs.
:react-native-navigation:compileReactNative57DebugJavaWithJavac (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 23,5,main]) started.

> Task :react-native-navigation:compileReactNative57DebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Caching disabled for task ':react-native-navigation:compileReactNative57DebugJavaWithJavac' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':react-native-navigation:compileReactNative57DebugJavaWithJavac' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has failed previously.
All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':react-native-navigation:compileReactNative57DebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

Help me please, a not working witch  react nativ.
Ask for any information.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade and reinstall your react-native-navigator version to ^3.2 and use RNN v3.
RNN v2 not work with react-native 060